# web parts - should they contain the form tag

Tags: asp.net, ajax

My aspx page contains a region which is populated trough ajax. The pupulated content is that of the page MyWebpart.aspx. But MyWebpart.aspx contains not only a grid(which is what I need to get trough ajax), it also contains , , ,  tags because this are required for any aspx file. Is there any problem with this?

code to replace inner html with that received from webpart

```
displayElement.innerHTML += executor.get_responseData();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to avoid InnerHTML, and create a new tag, than add it as a chield, and the form tag creates no problems